# SQL Server Best Practice - How to manage indexes on a large, diversely used table

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing, sql-server-2008-r2

I manage a SQL Server 2008 R2 single instance server.  I have one table that is my largest, as well as my most diversely used table.  It is basically an event table that logs about 400k events a day, and holds 13 months of history.

For the sake of this solution, changing the design of this table or the data in it is not an option.  Because this table is

- huge (135 million records, 41 GB in size)
- queried using a multitude of field combinations
- queried both by tools using consistently structured queries, as well as ad hoc queries
- important for queries to be relatively fast

managing Indexes on this table has been a bear.

The table currently has 1 clustered index (PK on an int identity field) and 23 Nonclustered indexes.  Total Index storage is 372 GB, 9x larger than the table itself.  The table is updated once per day, then all other activity is "SELECT" statements.  Most of the fields being used in WHERE clauses are varchar(50) fields, with a few datetime fields as well.

On the performance side, the table queries pretty quickly in nearly all situations, so no complaints there...

**ASK:**
I just wonder if there is a better way to index this table to make it more "generic" to support the multitude of ways it can be queried without taking up so much disk space...  Thoughts?  Looking for some high level theories or general best practices with a situation like this.

Comment: It depends on what query combinations you are running on this table,since you are saying,this table is updated only once per day,you can create different combination of  indexes and see if you are getting desired output.but any ways i dont see a need unless you are seeing some issues and you are in need of trying to make a query run fast

Comment: How many columns are there? And what has your indexing strategy been so far?

Comment: @TheGameiswar - My concern is more with the growth of index storage...  The table is queried VERY frequently, and when queries take longer than expected, I hear about it.  :-)  tinkering with it is not the most desirable.  I am just at a point where my storage is nearly maxed (cant justify the cost of a SAN to the boss', and have maxed my internal storage on the server.)  So I have to start being careful about the indexes I am adding.  Trying to see if I need to change my approach to this table specifically.

Comment: @SQLChao - There are 24 columns, not counting the primary key.  To date, My strategy has been as follows:  (1)  Each view created on the table was reviewed and indexing was created on all joined fields to support the view.  (2) Each time the table is referenced in a stored procedure or in an application, the query was ran through the optimizer, and recommended indexes and statistics were added.  End result is 10 indexes created by me, 13 indexes created at the recommendation of the optimizer.

Comment: You may need to look at how your existing indexes are used(usefull or not) and what are the type of queries that are being run against them.IMHO,there is no general combination which can work for all type of queries.you need to analyze your query patterns.

Comment: @DHL-JDParker I wouldn't create all the recommended indexes. For your particular situation I would look to see if can get an index to cover multiple queries versus tuning per query. It's a situation where you have to pick your battles since you are limited in your options. There are situations where SQL will recommend a new index when you could just add a column to an existing index to cover the query.

Comment: @TheGameiswar - Fair enough... that was my concern as well.  My challenge is that because the table is used for so many ad hoc queries, indexes can get used on an ad hoc query and mask it's "need" for standard queries against the table.  I might need to spend a couple of days and comb through the queries on this table and see how the current indexes are being used...

Comment: @SQLChao - Agreed... I think that is where I am now.  I'll have to come up with a nice clean way to view the indexes and see what can be consolidated.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: One last suggestion, use SQL Sentry's Plan Explorer if you aren't already. It's awesome and will really help you analyze the queries you are tuning more efficiently than the regular plan explorer.

Comment: Filtered indexes, where appropriate, might help

Answer (score 1):

The best indexing IMO is usage based - run Profiler, and capture the queries that are run for this table and fine tune for those queries.

If you're able to change the Partitioning or Clustered index strategy, this would give you a big boost.

Q: Why is there a PK on an Identity column on a table used for reporting purposes?  Is it heavily used in `JOINs`? If not, is it merely for uniqueness?

Comment: You can also use plan cache, it's usually quite reliable source for finding queries with large I/O, and doesn't require anything to be setup / running.

Comment: Agree on usage based indexing... that is how the indexes have been created to date.  My concern is that each time we add a new report that needs to join to this table in a different way than previous reports, profiling and adding a new index can frequently add another 16 to 20 GB of index data to the server.  Trying to see if there is a better way to do it as opposed to creating a new custom index for each reporting view we deploy.

Comment: In regards to partitioning...  unfortunately that isn't an option as this is a Standard Edition license, not an enterprise license (haven't been able to get the boss' to approve the cost for an enterprise edition license.)

Comment: and finally in regards to the question on the PK, the data in this table is an import from a Oracle DB that supports the actual production application.  The PK used in the oracle DB is a 50 character string, so I chose to create my own INT PK for performance reasons.  When importing the data to this table, I use the original PK to ensure no duplicated records are imported, but I create my own INT key on my table.  Hope this helps...

Comment: @JamesZ - My concern isn't necessarily with finding needed indexes.  I am able to do that pretty consistently.  I'm more concerned with finding an indexing strategy that is able to handle "diverse" queries without a lot of large indexes to support them.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if there are indexes you could combine into one index.
- The column order for INCLUDED Columns is irrelevant. For example:

```
Index 1: 
Key Columns (A, B, C, D, E) Includes (L, M, N) 
Index 2: 
Key Columns (A, B, C, D, E, F, G) Includes (N, M, L)
```

So you could drop Index 1. But you may do more I/O because Index 2 is larger.
On the other hand, you do not have to have the two Indexes in RAM and on disk/backup.

It also can be that the changing the order of less selective index columns doesn't cost much more. As you may know the order of the key columns in an index should be from most selective first to more and more lesser selective columns.

Do you want the same indexing strategy for actual data as for older data? So you could use filtered indexes and use less indexes for older data and a more flexible index strategy for newer data. Older data may not be queried as fast as it does today. But how often it is queried in comparison to new data?

Comment: I agree with your approach.  A filtered index is something I hadn't thought of, so I will look at that as well to see if there are some queries that can be limited in scope to reduce disk usage.  I assume that the "WHERE" clause of the Create Index statement would be applied when the index is rebuilt, or new data is inserted to the table? For example, if I use WHERE dtmHandledDate >= DATEADD(DAY, -60, GETDATE()) on the filter, when would records be dropped from the index once they no longer matched the WHERE?  I assume only at rebuild.  I'll look into that.  Thanks for your input!

Comment: A filtered index will only be updated if you INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE  rows (well, and TRUNCATE TABLE :-), and data in the rows meet the filter predicate of the index. You can't use non-deterministic functions like DATEADD. This would mean SQL-Server would have to check every predicate constantly. But it doesn't. So you have to use a fixed date-range in the WHERE-Clause of the filter. To Change the filter predicate use ALTER INDEX....

Comment: Interesting.  Thanks for the tip!  I'll definitely look into it more.